# Type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage in helper type

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to execute the error handling component class within my program but keep getting the following error message:

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'Marketplace.ErrorHandlingComponent.Invoke(System.Func, int,
>   System.TimeSpan)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   the type arguments explicitly.

I'm not sure what is meant by **try specifying the type arguments explicitly**.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public void SetPlotList(int filterReference)
    {
        // Fill plot list view
        List<PlotComponent.PlotList> plotList = PlotComponent.SelectPlotLists(filterReference);

        // Find the plot list item in the new list
        PlotComponent.PlotList selectPlotList =
            plotList.Find(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.PlotId) == _focusPlotReference);

        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            (() =>
            {
                PlotListView.ItemsSource = plotList;
                if (selectPlotList != null)
                {
                    PlotListView.SelectedItem = selectPlotList;
                }
            }));

        int jobSum = 0;
        int bidSum = 0;
        foreach (PlotComponent.PlotList item in PlotListView.Items)
        {
            jobSum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Jobs);
            bidSum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Bids);
        }

        // Determine job/bid list ratio
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new ThreadStart(() => JobBidRatioTextBlock.Text = jobSum + " jobs - " + bidSum + " bids"));
    }

    private void ValidateTextbox()
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(FilterTextBox.Text, "[^0-9]") || FilterTextBox.Text == "") return;
        try
        {
            ErrorHandlingComponent.Invoke(() => SetPlotList(Convert.ToInt32(FilterTextBox.Text)), 3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
        catch
        {
            FilterTextBox.Text = null;
        }
    }
```

**ErrorHandlingComponent.cs**

```
    public static T Invoke<T>(Func<T> func, int tryCount, TimeSpan tryInterval)
    {
        if (tryCount < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tryCount");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (--tryCount > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(tryInterval);
                    continue;
                }
                LogError(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your lambda is `SetPlotList(Convert.ToInt32(FilterTextBox.Text))`.

`SetPlotList` returns `void`, but `Invoke` assumes that the lambda provided to it returns some (non-void) type.  It can't infer the type that the lambda returns *because it doesn't return a type*.  `SetPlotList` returned something, then that `Invoke` call would function properly.

Comment: How can I adjust the `Invoke` call to cater for methods that return void and non-void types?

Comment: @methuselah It would need to accept a delegate that doesn't return a value.  If it needs to also not accept any parameters, then `Action` would be applicable.  Of course, the method's implementation would need to be altered significantly if to account for the fact that the delegate has no return value.  You could write a second non-generic overload, if you want to be able to have both.

Answer (score 0):

`SetPlotList` is a void method, but `ErrorHandlingComponent.Invoke` expects a `Func<T>` as its first parameter. It needs to invoke the Func and will return the func's return value. Since you're trying to pass it a void method, the compiler complains.

Comment: How can I adjust the `Invoke` call to cater for methods that return void and non-void types?